# starting a new activity within android without animation

Tags: android-listview, android-activity, android

I'd like to start a new `Activity` when clicking an item of a `ListView`. This `Activity` will have exactly the same design (`ActionBar` + `ListView`) except that all the style and objects in the `ListView` will be different.

I thought the best way would be to separate them in two activities, however while transitioning between the two activities an animation is  displayed and it makes the transition looks like its lagging.

**First question**: Is there a way to start a new `Activity` that is only a `ListView` and  have it replace my current `ListView` while not touching my main window and statusbar?

**Secondly**: If not then is it possible to remove the transition animation between two activities?

Comment: are the contents the same? or you just change the style of the listview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the same activity you can call setAdapter again on the ListView and give it a new adapter (which can then have different data/row layouts etc).